# What's the difference beween poly2tri getTriangles() and getMap()?

Tags: c++, triangulation, delaunay

I've searched all along the internets and can't find a clear meaning for the next two routines at poly2tri:

```
  /**
   * Get CDT triangles
   */
  std::vector<Triangle*> GetTriangles();

  /**
   * Get triangle map
   */
  std::list<Triangle*> GetMap();
```

The only difference I find is the container type, you can see [the full source here](https://github.com/jhasse/poly2tri/blob/master/poly2tri/sweep/cdt.h)

Apart from it, [the only documented reference is this](https://github.com/jhasse/poly2tri/blob/master/testbed/main.cc).

```
/// Constrained triangles
vector<Triangle*> triangles;
/// Triangle map
list<Triangle*> map;
```

So what's the difference between them? I've been using getTriangles() to draw an OpenGL mesh and it works fine but I'm worried about it being wrong.

Comment: What is the `size()` of the vector resp the list those functions return if invoked just one after another?

Answer (score 1):

When you triangulate a simple polygon you can also get triangles outside the border of the polygon when the polygon is concave.

I think the map contains all triangles and GetTriangles only return the triangles inside the given polygon.